# How to make the "@" symbol work in a formula inside of a macro in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below macro:

```vb
Sub GenerateTestData()
    Range("F3:F151").Formula = "= $B2 & ""."" & $D2 & "@gmail.come""
End Sub
```

There is an issues with the @ symbol, and I am not sure how to make it work as a string.

Comment: `"= $B2 & ""."" & $D2 & ""@gmail.com"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close out this question: You have quotes issues:

```
"= $B2 & ""."" & $D2 & ""@gmail.com"""
```